# complete windows app development on hyper-v virtual machine

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am about to buy a Windows 8 enabled machine and I intend to write a windows mobile app. I don't have access to any windows 8 machine but I am really curious about one feature.

Can I use hyper-v virtual machine of windows 8.1 guest OS to emulate windows phones? I mean complete app development in virtual machine itself. I suspect that virtualization of hardware could be a problem like in windows 7 virtual machine on oracle VirtualBox.

I intend not to install visual studio on host OS, probably its the best way to keep it working for years. Windows OS is touchy.

Comment: So want to run Windows 8.1 with a virtual machine with Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone emulator?

Comment: @IgorKulman : yes, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not with Hyper-V. You have to use VMWare. VMWare supports nested virtualization. You disable Hyper-V in your host OS, install VMWare, enabled nested virtualization in VMWare and than you can install and enable Hyper-V (needed by the emulators) in the guest OS.

Comment: thanks...you are correct. I also found this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27606.windows-phone-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-a-virtual-machine-with-working-emulator.aspx
which explains it all step by step.

Comment: As of windows 10 TH2 (10586.n), hyper-v supports nested hypervisors (although it's not widely known, yet)